# When i plug a desktop computer into wall port #3 i get a 192. ip address when i plug it into a different port i get the ip address 10.

Tags: networking

Thats basically the issue a week ago a user was complaining that they can no longer get on the internet. So when I did an ipconfig/all it returned an address of 10.when it was working. Now when it stopped connecting to the internet and  i did a ipconfig/all it returned an address of 192.  So my question is how did the ports get changed because i checked the computer and plugged it into a working port and it connects immediate and then i plug the same computer back into the bad port and it doesnt connect.

Need an idea what to check for or investigate.

Comment: We cannot answer your question without knowing what is on the other end of the cable terminating in wall port #3. If you find out then you can probably answer your own question ...

Answer (score 3):

You have a rogue DHCP server somewhere on the network.  The main router appears to be giving out a 10 series address scheme.  From the port #3, seems if you trace it back, there is a router somewhere that is giving out a 192 address scheme.  May have happened if someone was using a router as a switch.

Comment: Is there a free download program or sniffer that can see if thats the case. Also how would a router/switch be configured to do something like that.  Was there a configuration change?

Comment: It is the nature of a router that it gives out addresses.  Look for someone who plugged some sort of device into the LAN.  Basically it sounds like someone needed an additional port and thought using the router as a switch was a good idea.  If you turn off the DHCP, you can do this,  If the power goes out or something resets the router, you get this kind of problem.

Comment: So you are basically saying that its possible that a Router/Switch was daisychained to another Router/Switch that was set to only be a switch but due to a power surge it somehow change roles?  There was a power surge and some work done on the network but it would be good to know for information purposes anyway exactly why this happened  but from what you are saying if both routers decide to issue out ip addresses this can happen? and that is because they were both set to DHCP?  Is there a command to see which router is issuing ip addresses or a tool to pinpoint this type of issue next time

Comment: If your main and authorized router was issuing 10. addresses and everything was fine and someone needed additional ports, they could have plugged in a router on a line downstream from it.  If DHCP was turned off, then it was acting just like a switch.  If something turned it on, then it would start handing out addresses according to its settings.  How to see which router - just find them and plug into one of the ports and see what IP address you get.  Tool to pinpoint - sorry, you have to trace the wiring.